# How to prevent date/time from changing php

Tags: php

I want to prevent duplicate image file uploads by adding a date/time to the file name.

I have an image preview and if the user uploads the image file, the file is sent to a folder with a date time stamp. When the user fills out the form and posts the image and form details to the database the image minutes change on the image file.

The problem I'm having is when the image file is sent to the folder a date time is set eg. image 17 10 2017 10 18.jpg but when I create the image path for the database the minutes change eg. image 17 10 2017 10 19.jpg.

1)file sent to folder using Ajax ie. filename.date.extension
2)file path sent to database after form filled out ie. filepath/filename.date.extension

Date/time does not match 1) is supposed to be equal to 2)

```
 <?php

  // Uploaded file sent via AJAX
  $mainImg = $_FILES['mainImg']['name'];

  $ext   = pathinfo($mainImg, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $justname = basename($mainImg,".$ext");

  // Prevent duplicate
  $pd = date(" d m y H i ");

  // 6)Rename the main Image 
  $dateAdded = $justname.$pd.".".$ext;

  FILE IS SENT TO THE FOLDER THEN WHEN FORM IS FILLED OUT AND POSTED ALL 
  INFO GOES TO DATABASE...
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $directory = "Images/";
  $filetodatabase = $directory.$dateAdded;

  //CONNECT AND INSERT DATA INTO DATABASE USING MYSQL
  }
```

Comment: So you generate one timestamp upon AJAX file upload and second one upon form submit? Yes, these two timestamps might be different. You should send the timestamp back to browser upon the AJAX file upload completion, store it in a hidden form input. And do not generate the timestamp again Use the one stored in your hidden input. This way it wil be the same.

Comment: Thanks , I generated a random number, sent it via AJAX with the image and simultaneously sent the same number to a hidden input. I had to split the Ajax upload file and form upload file.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the timestamp once. Send it over to other components if you ever need it again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a timestamp or date, use the file hash to prevent duplicate uploads.

See the PHP Manual for the following two:

- [`md5_file`](http://php.net/md_file) — Calculates the md5 hash of a given file
- [`sha1_file`](http://php.net/sha1_file) — Calculate the sha1 hash of a file